# Installing OpenCV on Linux Suse 11 SP0

Tags: linux, opencv, suse

I am currently trying to install OpenCV on Linux but it seems that there is no easy to do this. I looked for many ways but it seems I'm always forgetting some packages. When running "cmake" there are always error on the first seconds.

Does anyone know a simple solution to install OpenCV with the appropriate dependencies on Linux Suse 11 SP0 ?

**EDIT:**
I would like to keep my actual configuration regarding the packages installed on Linux. The goal here is too keep the same configuration of Gcc, glibc, libstd... in order to avoid to having to test every software again with the new configuration.

I have Linux Suse 11 SP0 with:

- libstd++33
- gcc 4.3.62

Is there a way to install any version of OpenCV without upgrading those dependencies ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: why don't you install via system package manger `zypper` ?

Comment: Because I am trying to not upgrade every single package of my system. If using zypper it will upgrade libstdc, glibc, etc... The goal here is to have a clean installation without modifying the current Suse configuration... That is why I'm having trouble installing it

Comment: If `zypper install opencv` updates your `libstdc, glibs, ...` this means that it depends on them. Please make clear what are you requirements, what version of opencv you need and be sure that you have all the dependencies intalled on the system.

Comment: Hi deimus, checkout my edited post. Thank you

Comment: Check the dependencies for each `opencv` version. Most probably you'll need to install old version of it, in order to not update your configuration.